# Automatically Highlight Navigation Links on Horizontal Free Scrolling Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, addclass, horizontal-scrolling

I have a particular page with a set of images contained in a `white-space:nowrap` div, so the page scrolls horizontally. There's a fixed (main) navigation menu on the left.

I have a second navigation set, underneath the images, which when you click on the various links uses `scrollTo` to scroll the browser to the relevant image. This second navigation menu is contained in a fixed div and made up of a series of links to the various anchors associated with the images.

I would like a way of attaching and removing an active class to these links (i.e. `addClass()` ) depending on where the browser window is (and what is in view).

I have found lots of vertical versions of this, but my JS knowledge isn't fantastic and I haven't been able to successfully convert these to be used horizontally.

Essentially what I would like is a horizontal version of this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3V6Y/).

I have come across this plugin, but haven't managed to get this to work for me either:
[here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport/3x2.html)

Thank you!

Comment: can you post a fiddle of yours? Also have a look into [http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this your fiddle horizontal:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3V6Y/

I made a little change on HTML, and here is the JS:

```
$(function(){
    var sections = {},
        _width  = $(window).width(),
        i        = 0;

    // Grab positions of our sections 
    $('.section').each(function(){
        sections[this.name] = $(this).offset().left;
    });

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            pos   = $this.scrollLeft();

        for(i in sections){
            if(sections[i] >= pos && sections[i] <= pos + _width){
                $('a').removeClass('active');
                $('#nav_' + i).addClass('active');
            }  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers - this works a treat.

This is a fiddle with your JS and a few updates to CSS/HTML to make it work for horizontally scrolling websites, in case anyone else is interested: http://jsfiddle.net/x3V6Y/343/